# Iterate through Task List C#

Tags: c#, loops, asynchronous, async-await

I have code like this

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersByField(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(fieldName, fieldValue);
        var result = await _usersCollection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

When I trying to iterate it using

```
foreach(var w in GetUsersByField("Name", John"))
```

it shows error that

> "does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

I have tried using

```
public async IEnumerable<Task<List<User>>> GetUsersByField(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
```

but still shows error. Any suggestions?

Comment: your function is returning a `Task<List<User>>` and not a `List<User>`. So, it would be better to get the values first from the method `GetUsersByField()` as `var users = await GetUsersByField("Name", ""John");` and then do your `foreach(var w in users){//your code to process single entity goes here};`

Comment: Do not call `return result.ToList();`, `result` is a List already. `ToListAsync` returns List<T>

Comment: [Microsoft Pseudo-Recommends appending your method with Async ie `GetUsersByFieldAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With an `async` method like this:

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUsersByField(string fieldName, string fieldValue
```

It's advisable to `await` it:

```
public async Task MyCallingMethod()
{
    var users = await GetUsersByField(...);

    foreach(var w in users ) 
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

or:

```
public async Task MyCallingMethod()
{
    foreach(var user in await GetUsersByField(...)) 
    { 
       ... 
    }
}
```

There are other ways by calling `Result`, though let's not go down that rabbit hole.

In short, let your *Async Await Pattern* propagate like a virus through your code.

---

**Additional reading**

Stephen Cleary : [Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: Is it possible to call the GetUsersByField method from other Class?

Comment: @Skipm3 yes if you have an instance of the class its in.